# Is it possible to use Nodejs in javascript project

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I have a project to write to a postgress database from an html, in my project I included packages jquery, html, and css. I read that to access a postgress database it’s needed to have a server side package like nodejs, and I want to include this package in my project. I would appreciate if I can get sample projects or resources to do it.

Comment: Use expressjs and sequelizejs

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS isn't a Javascript package that you can run on a browser.

Let me explain.

NodeJS started out as a project to run Javascript code outside of the browser and on top of your Operating System. This gives it access to OS specific functionality like writing to files, writing to Databases, spawning processes, starting an HTTP server etc. Much like any other general purposes programming language like Python, Ruby, Java, PHP etc.

So NodeJS is two things - the Javascript Interpreter(same as the browsers, V8 to be specific) and Libraries (like fs, vm, zip, etc).

While most of these libraries are inter-operable with the Browser's version of the Javascript interpreter via something like Browserify (Used to run node.js modules on the browser), some of them like the libraries used to write to a database are not and cannot be used on the browser.

To use the postgress database JS library, you'd have to learn node.js and expressjs. But what would be practical is to find a library specific to the framework you are using, whether it is PHP, Ruby on Rails, Django/Python etc.